# How to display div only once in the loop and next div display inside div which run only once

Tags: php, html, loops

I try to found the solution on google and SO but I haven't got solution.

I have a code something like.

```
$index = 0;
while (some condition here) { 
         if ($index < 4) {?>
            <div class="first4">
              <p>Some text here</p>
            </div>
    <?php }
        else{
            $check=0;
            if ($check==0){?>
              <div class="displayOnceInwhile">
            <?php $check=1; }?>
            <div class="InsideaboveClass"></div>

    <?php } 

$index++;}?>
```

What I am doing with the above code is, if `$index` is less then 4 then the inner text will display else `$check` will run only once in the loop but it's not working. Also, Notice here I confused where should I closed the `displayOnceInwhile` closing `</div>`.

**Expected result**

```
<!--first 4 will display-->
    <div class="first4"><p>Some text here</p></div>
     <div class="first4"><p>Some text here</p></div>
     <div class="first4"><p>Some text here</p></div>
     <div class="first4"><p>Some text here</p></div>
<!--Set will display like this-->
     <div class="displayOnceInwhile">
      <div class="InsideaboveClass"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have `$check=0;` on the line before you check it - so it will always be 0, try putting it before your `while`.

Comment: @NigelRen, Let me try this

Comment: @NigelRen, one more think. I haven't closed this div. Where should I close the div for  this       <div class="displayOnceInwhile">?

Comment: Can you please add expected result with this ?

Comment: @Prifulnath, Updated result in the question.

Comment: You can simply close the div outside the loop and $check=0; at the before loop. Or you can use two loops to do this.

Comment: @Prifulnath, I have closed the if condition at the top only. I mean this one  if ($check==0){?>
              <div class="displayOnceInwhile">
            <?php $check=1; }?> and I have to dipslay only once this div

Comment: I have added an answer hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope This is what you are trying to do is.

```
<?php
$check = 0;
$index = 0;
while (some condition here) { 
    if ($index < 4) {
        echo '<div class="first4"><p>Some text here</p></div>';
    } else {
        if ($check==0){
            echo '<div class="displayOnceInwhile">';
            $check=1;
        }
        echo '<div class="InsideaboveClass"></div>';
    }
    $index++;
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check

Answer (score 1):

You could use following to build your HTML

```
<?php
$first = '<div class="first4" ><p > Some text here </p ></div >';
$firstOpen = '<div class="first4" ><p > Some text here </p >';
$firstClose = '</div>';
$once = '<div class="displayOnceInwhile"><div class="InsideaboveClass"></div>';

$index = 0;
while ($index < 3) {
    echo $first;
    $index++;
}
echo $firstOpen;
echo $once;
echo $firstClose;
```